# How to session timeout if page refresh in php?

Tags: php

I am developing a exam application and I want that when user give exam than on that time no one can reload my page.

I want to destroy session if my page refresh. I started the session on each page and after relevant session variables are set, the session is destroyed each time the page is refreshed or when I browse the same URL on a different tab.

Comment: I don't quite get the intent, but if you don't want to keep the session up... then don't use it...?

Comment: Clear your question.

Comment: I don't precept what you are trying to achieve here. Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: i have requirement of session but on  page refresh i want to destroy.

Comment: and why would you want that? what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am developing a exam application and i want that when user give exam than on that time No one can reload my page

Comment: @SANJAYJARIYA sometimes requirements can be really stupid so just ignore that and don't use session in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `session_destroy()` to destroy a session.

However the whole point of sessions is to persist data between page refreshes; if you want to destroy this data each refresh it would be easier not to use a session.

What are you storing in the session; this might make a solution to your problem clearer? I.e. what lines of your code use `$_SESSION`? Please post some. Maybe it's an external library that taps into the session?

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck in same kind of problem.

Just declare a session variable `$_SESSION['page_load_count'] = 0;` while creating/setting session after authentication.

Then just check this variable on exam.php page load if the value is 0 then continue loading the page and at the end of script just do a `$_SESSION['page_load_count']++;` else if value of `$_SESSION['page_load_count']>0` then show that the page has been refreshed.